# How to configure plist for Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, plist

With my limited technical skills, I am not sure how to read the following step from Facebook.

> Create an array key called URL types with a single array sub-item
>   called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your app ID prefixed
>   with fb.

So what I think I should is

1. Create a Key of Type Array and call the key `URL types`
2. Open `item 0` of the array and in there create an array called `URL Schemes`

So at this point the progression in the plist is `URL types > Item 0 > URL Schemes`, where `URL Schemes` is also an array. Is this correct? Also for the final step, if my app id is 12345, then I should have it as `fb12345` with no space between fb and 12345. So in the end my key is `URL types > Item 0 > URL Schemes > Item 0` and my single value is `fb12345`.

**UPDATE**

Here is a picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See attached picture of how one of the apps I work on is configured[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, but I can't quite make sense of it. My layout for `URL Types` is in tree form whereas yours has a pictorial layout. So I have updated to add an image to the post. Maybe that will help. Sorry I couldn't use your generous help, but my knowledge of iOS is a bit limited to map your layout to mine.

Comment: You are looking directly into your plist file. To see what I see, go your project's settings (click on your project name in the file list on the left) and click on the Info tab as seen in my picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Here insert your AppID

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>401043023425XXX</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>logindemo</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>akamaihd.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>fbcdn.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb401043023425XXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: You might want to briefly explain your code example, and what it fixes in the OP's issue. Otherwise the post can get flagged as low quality in the review queue. Thanks.